# Proving that $f(z) = \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}$ is a surjective map on the unit disk for fixed $w \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that  $f(z) = \frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}$ is a surjective map on the unit disk for a fixed $w \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$ (i.e. $f$ maps the unit disk to itself).

Here's what I've got:

I have been able to show that $|\frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}| < 1$ if $|w|<1$ and $|z|<1$.

Let $z \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$. Then $|z| < 1$, and similarly $|w| < 1$, so that $$f(z) = |\frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}| < 1 \implies f(z) \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$$

This implies that every element in the unit disk gets mapped to an element in the unit disk under $f$. Moreover, if we let $f(z) \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$, then we get that
$$|\frac{w-z}{1-\bar{w}z}| < 1 \implies |z|^2 + |w|^2 - |w|^2|z|^2 < 1 \implies |z|^2(1-|w|^2) < 1 - |w|^2 \implies |z|^2 < 1$$

and so $|z|<1$, so that $z \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$. Thus (combining with the earlier result) we get

$z \in \mathbb{D}_1(0) \iff f(z) \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$

I feel like I'm so close to proving surjectivity here, but to me this does not seem to imply that *every* element of the unit disk gets mapped to (please do correct me if I'm wrong).

I tried assuming towards contradiction that there exists a $u \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$ such that $F(z) \ne u \space\space\space\forall z \in \mathbb{D}_1(0)$, but had trouble seeing where this would lead me.

Next, I tried to reason that the unit disk is simply connected, so if I can prove $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{D}_1(0)$, then $f(\mathbb{D}_1(0))$ is simply connected, implying there are no holes, and so the map is surjective.

To do this, I found it easier to prove $f$ was analytic on $\mathbb{D}_1(0)$, which implies continuity. My reasoning was as follows:

using the limit definition of a complex derivative, the numerator of $f$ has a derivative of $1$, and similarly, the denominator has a derivative of $\bar{w}$. This implies that the quotient of these two (i.e $f$), has a derivative when $w \ne 0$. If $w = 0$, then $f(z) = z$, which clearly has a derivative of 1. Thus, $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}_1(0)$.

I'm happy with this method, but in my class, we proved that if $f$ is continuous on a connected set $E$, then $f(E)$ is connected. We never proved this to be true for a simply connected set, so I'm not sure I should use this argument.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to write down the inverse of $f$. It is
$$g(z)=\frac{z-w}{\overline{w}z-1}.$$
For similar reasons, it maps the unit disc to itself, and $f\circ g$
and $g\circ f$ are both the identity map.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was doing (and indeed had just found the inverse to be the original function) right before you posted. I was editing the question, but you beat me to it :) So best answer for you